# Error on odoo 12 after installation and db creation

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I have to start using odoo 12 on my job but I can't start using it, I have already 5 days searching on google to find an answer.
I would be very grateful if you could please help me, with some of your wisdom :)
After I install odoo on my computer and visit localhost:8069 for first time it asks me to create my database but after I do this it doesn't load the login page instead it gives me an 500 internal server error with this console log every time I refresh the page:

```
2020-10-12 18:31:41,068 21425 ERROR prueba werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/service/server.py", line 434, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 1488, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 212, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 182, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 776, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 208, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 835, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 342, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 1270, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/http.py", line 1263, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"].render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1324, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1333, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 59, in render
    result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 275, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "<decorator-gen-54>", line 2, in compile
    
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 114, in compile
    return super(IrQWeb, self).compile(id_or_xml_id, options=options)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 338, in compile
    raise QWebException("Error when compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: Name node can't be used with 'None' constant
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb.compile at 0x7f3b32b84280>, 173, ('en_US', None, None, None, None, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo12/entvirt/src/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 330, in compile
    unsafe_eval(compile(astmod, '<template>', 'exec'), ns)
ValueError: Name node can't be used with 'None' constant

Error when compiling AST
ValueError: Name node can't be used with 'None' constant
Template: 173
Path: /templates/t/t/form/input[2]
Node: <input type="hidden" name="redirect" t-att-value="redirect"/> - - -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with python 3.8.5.Try applying this fix https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/55305/commits/5baf0f2130b8d27d50aa60b54d68a5fc57b127a0

Comment: is it posible to downgrade python version on the local enviroment?

Comment: I confirm that, applyting manually the changes to qweb.py and ir_qweb.py the fix works. (Python 3.8.0 Ubuntu Server 20.0 and Odoo 12 communiy)